# How create movement buttons left/right?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Please help. I am a beginner on Swift. I've added sprites for player and left/right buttons. But how can I add an action for every button and apply these actions to the player?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var player: SKSpriteNode!
    var leftMove: SKSpriteNode!
    var rightMove: SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        player = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "player")

        player.position = CGPoint(x:127, y:125)

        addChild(player)


        leftMove = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "leftMove")

        leftMove.position = CGPoint(x:80, y:35)

        leftMove.size = CGSize (width: 55, height: 55)

        addChild(leftMove)


        rightMove = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "rightMove")

        rightMove.position = CGPoint(x:160, y:35)

        rightMove.size = CGSize (width: 55, height: 55)

        addChild(rightMove)

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self


    }
```

Comment: You probably want to look into the `touchesBegan` method for iOS, or whatever the Mac equivalent is.  You could then check if `rightMove.contains(touchLocation)`.  And from there it depends on how you want to move the `player`, `SKAction`, physics body impulse, or setting the `x` and `y` position?

Comment: I dont know what better for platformer game. Maybe x/y position or SKAction.  I cant understand how working this process...i mean: Sprite(Buttons)+sprite(player).

Comment: I haven't built a platformer before, but my guess would be physics body.  Maybe using `player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector)` to jump, and setting the `player.physicsBody?.velocity.dx` for controlling left and right movement?  Don't forget that this would involve creating a physics body for the `player`.  I would also suggest looking at a few other platformer games to see how they handled movement.  See if you can break down into smaller parts how they handle movement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the buttons a unique name like:

```
leftMove.name = "Left"
rightMove.name = "Right"
```

Implement the logic in touchesBegan:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

  /* Called when a touch begins */
  for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if (node.name == "Left") {
        // Implement your logic for left button touch here:
        player.position = CGPoint(x:player.position.x-1, y:player.position.y)
    } else if (node.name == "Right") {
        // Implement your logic for right button touch here:
        player.position = CGPoint(x:player.position.x+1, y:player.position.y)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow.  My recommendation is that for each button that you would like to have actions on, that you subclass SKSpriteNode for those objects.  This way you can leverage the touchesBegan:, touchesMoved: and touchesEnded: functions for each of these objects individually.  For example:

As promised, here is a more robust version of a subclassed SKSpriteNode.  Also, I tested it in one of my projects and I can attest to it working correctly:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class SubclassedSKSpriteNode: SKSpriteNode {
    init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "whateverImage.png")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())
        userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = (touches.first! ).locationInNode(scene!)
        position = scene!.convertPoint(location, toNode: parent!)

        print("touchesBegan: \(location)")
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = (touches.first! ).locationInNode(scene!)
        position = scene!.convertPoint(location, toNode: parent!)

        print("touchesMoved: \(location)")

    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = (touches.first! ).locationInNode(scene!)
        position = scene!.convertPoint(location, toNode: parent!)

        print("touchesEnded: \(location)")
    }
}
```

Also, to add this button to your SKScene (or any other SKNode):

```
let button = SubclassedSKSpriteNode()
button.position = CGPointMake(420, 300)
addChild(button)
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks man.  But what need add on func touchBegan? How add action for buttons?

Comment: I am at work right now but when I get home tonight I'll provide a more robust sample code.  In the meantime, I think there are lots of sample touch implementations scattered throughout SO.  For what its worth, I think you should probably use touchesEnded: instead of touchesBegan: for buttons.

Comment: There you go!  I added a fully functioning subclass of the SKSpriteNode.  Where I have the print statements in the touch functions is where you would add your own code.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks man))this working..if i understand right..Will i  need add SKAction for my player?

Comment: Whether you use SKAction for anything related to your player is a stylistic choice I think.  I use SKAction for minor effects on buttons and other SKNodes.  For example, if I want to fade a control in or fade it out, or if I want to make a button bigger when pressed.  You could use an SKAction to move your player around but it doesn't seem efficient to me.  I guess it depends on how you want to design the game!

Comment: I added buttons and SKCameraNode for my player))but i got other problem. When player moving right all buttons dont follow for him.